# How do I find incorrectly nested data in mongdb?

Tags: mongodb

Incorrect nested data written to Mongo. How to fix it?

```
# the correct data
{"username": "Alex Cataord", "age": 22, "favor": [1, 2, 3]}

# but some data is wrong
{"username": "Michael Cala", "age": 38, "favor": [1, 2, [3, 4]]}
```

I tried the following, but cluster down (OOM)

```
db.user.find({"favor":{"$elemMatch": {"$type": 4}}})
```

It's a lot of data, can delete some data

I do not know how to resolve this

Comment: You can use the aggregation array operator `$filter` (along with your `$type` condition) to find the documents with "something is wrong" documents.

Comment: your find query is correct just put limit at the end `.limit(10)`. any limit number..

Comment: Yes, but very slowly @prasad_

Comment: yes, the fisrt tried I forgot it... @turivishal

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is just use a single update and let Mongo work it's magic, like so:

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  "favor": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$type": 4
    }
  }
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "favor": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$favor",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      {
                        $type: "$$this"
                      },
                      "array"
                    ]
                  },
                  "$$this",
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EdFrvmikj1B)

Depending on scale obviously this will take some time to run, but it's much faster than loading in each document into memory.

(Available for Mongo v4.2+)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this query will cause cluster OOM,  that's my problem. The `updateMany` and `find` expain should be the same.

Comment: Then you should split the update into multiple updates, add to the query a condition that partitions your data ( you can also use the `_id` field `_id: {$lt: someObjectId}` ). there is no "magic" solution that will make it work.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.